# React editable listbox won't re-render the entire list

Tags: reactjs

I'm building an editable listbox in React and the functionality works well on the back-end, but on the front-end it doesn't re-render correctly. You can do 6 operations with this component. You can rename an element, you can swap it with the element above, you can swap it with the element below, you can delete the element, you can insert an element above the current one, and you can insert a new element to the end.

The issue that I'm running into in more detail is that the current element that's being edited is the only one that re-renders, not the other elements that get changed from the operations.

Here is what the component looks like:
[image: Editable ListBox]

Here is the source code:

```
export const EditableList = ({label, elements}) => {
    const classNames = (...classes) => {
        return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ');
    };

    const [values, setValues] = useState([...elements]);

    return (
        <>
            <label className='font-medium block text-sm leading-6 text-gray-400'>{label}</label>
            <div>
                {values.map((value, key) => {
                    const changeItem = (e) => {
                        values[key] = e.target.value;
                    };

                    const moveItemUp = (e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        const newValues = values.slice();
                        const temp = values[key - 1];
                        newValues[key - 1] = values[key];
                        newValues[key] = temp;
                        setValues(newValues);
                    };

                    const deleteItem = (e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        setValues(values.filter((_, index) => {
                            return index !== key;
                        }));
                    };

                    const addItem = (e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        setValues([...values.slice(0, key), '', ...values.slice(key)]);
                        // setElements(prevElements => [...prevElements.slice(0, key), '', ...prevElements.slice(key)]);
                    };

                    const moveItemDown = (e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        const newValues = values.slice();
                        const temp = values[key + 1];
                        newValues[key + 1] = values[key];
                        newValues[key] = temp;
                        setValues(newValues);
                    };

                    return (
                        <div key={key} className="mt-2 flex">
                            <input
                                spellCheck='false'
                                type='text'
                                className="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 bg-transparent text-gray-400 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-500 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6 disabled:bg-gray-700"
                                defaultValue={value}
                                onChange={changeItem}
                            />
                            <div className='ml-4 flex space-x-2'>
                                <SecondaryButton
                                    className={classNames('text-gray-400 bg-gray-900 px-3 py-2 border border-gray-900',
                                        'font-semibold rounded-md hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-950')}
                                    disabled={key === 0}
                                    onClick={moveItemUp}>
                                    ^
                                </SecondaryButton>
                                <SecondaryButton type="button"
                                    value={key}
                                    className={classNames('text-red-400 bg-gray-900 px-3 py-2 border border-gray-900',
                                        'font-semibold rounded-md hover:bg-red-950 active:bg-gray-950',
                                        'hover:border-red-950')}
                                    onClick={deleteItem}>
                                    -
                                </SecondaryButton>
                                <SecondaryButton
                                    className={classNames('text-green-400 bg-gray-900 px-3 py-2 border border-gray-900',
                                        'font-semibold rounded-md hover:bg-green-950 active:bg-gray-950',
                                        'hover:border-green-950')}
                                    onClick={addItem}>
                                    +
                                </SecondaryButton>
                                <SecondaryButton
                                    className={classNames('text-gray-400 bg-gray-900 px-3 py-2 border border-gray-900',
                                        'font-semibold rounded-md hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-950')}
                                    onClick={moveItemDown} disabled={key === values.length - 1}>
                                    v
                                </SecondaryButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
            <SecondaryButton className='mt-4' onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                setValues([...values, '']);
            }}>Add To Bottom</SecondaryButton>
        </>
    );
};
EditableList.propTypes = {
    label: PropTypes.string,
    elements: PropTypes.array,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const changeItem = (e) => {
  values[key] = e.target.value;
};
```

This is wrong - you're mutating state.

```
const changeItem = (e) => setValues(v => v.map((existing,index) => index === key ? e.target.value : existing)
```

This piece is also wrong:

```
<input
    spellCheck='false'
    type='text'
    defaultValue={value}
    onChange={changeItem}
/>
```

Your component is controlled so you shouldn't be using `defaultValue={value}` and should be using `value={value}`

Also, while it's probably ok for you because it doesn't appear like your components are stateful, you shouldn't use the index in the array as your key, you should use a unique identifier on the item, if available.

```
  <div key={SOMETHING_UNIQUE_TO_THE_ITEM} className="mt-2 flex">
```